# Experiments are not working

Tags: smarttarget, experiment

View / Conversions are getting Null in my DD4T based Web Application, I am getting horizontal line for View/Conversion Graph.

[image]

My Findings :
In my Experiments component presentation i have a link, say link text then if i see the source code of the final page, the link must be converted to something like href="/redirect?url=x.y.....">link text .
But it is not happening in my case.

Comment: If the link is not showing as a URL, then maybe the target of that link is not published?

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares , It is showing as a URL, but if i have a url say <a href="x.y">link text</a> then if i see the source code of the final page, the link must be converted to something like <a href="/redirect?url=x.y.....">link text</a> , which is not happening .

Comment: Are you using the tags/controls? Or just doing your own query using the API?

Comment: @PeterKjaer it is a DD4T application. I just configured Experiments as mentioned in SDL Docs,  i am seeing all those experiments on my web pages. I am not using any tags/controls or API's, which API should i use ?

Comment: That depends on the particular DD4T implementation. I know, for instance, that DXA does not currently support Experiments (but the next version will, coming out very soon).

Comment: It seems a problem with the DD4T implemenation as Peter Kjaer said. Have you tried in a normal publication (non dd4t)? Also the Experiment configuration of the SDL Docs, don't seem to refer to a dd4t implementation?